# AttributeError: module 'midi' has no attribute 'read_midifile'

Tags: python, midi

I am getting this error: `AttributeError: module 'midi' has no attribute 'read_midifile'`

I have tried all the solutions that are available on GitHub.

I have also tried to reinstall the module and the most suggested solution for python3 was:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/vishnubob/python-mid i@feature/python3
```

but still, it's giving me this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: after importing *midi*, try `print(midi)`. It will give you the file name that contains the module (smth like: *../midi/\_\_init\_\_.py*). Add that location in the question. Then check for a file named *fileio.py* next to the previous one. Check the last 10 rows inside. Do they contain `read_midifile`?

Comment: No it does not contain fileio.py !

Comment: I think that's the problem. If you look in *\_\_init\_\_.py* does it contain `from fileio import *`?

Comment: No, it has only `from .midi import *`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you.

And I solved the problem by using this. try this!

pip3 install git+https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi@feature/python3

or

pip install git+https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi@feature/python3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, see how to write a good answer on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer